# How to replace my 'for' loop to find min/max by STL mimax algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, minmax

I have to find the min/max values (min x, min y, max x, max y) from a

```
vector<cv::Point>
```

Here my code:

```
vector<cv::Point> contour;
```

...

```
Min = Point(640, 480) ;
Max = Point(0,0) ;
for (int j=0; j<(int)contour.size(); j++)
{
    if (contour[j].x < Min.x) Min.x = contour[j].x ;
    if (contour[j].y < Min.y) Min.y = contour[j].y ;
    if (contour[j].x > Max.x) Max.x = contour[j].x ;
    if (contour[j].y > Max.y) Max.y = contour[j].y ;
}
```

This works fine. I developped a version using mimmax STL:

```
auto XminXmax = minmax_element(contour.begin(), contour.end(), [](Point p1,Point p2) {return p1.x < p2.x; });
auto YminYmax = minmax_element(contour.begin(), contour.end(), [](Point p1,Point p2) {return p1.y < p2.y; });
Point Min = Point((*XminXmax.first).x, (*YminYmax.first).y );
Point Max = Point((*XminXmax.second).x, (*YminYmax.second).y );
```

This also works fine and give the same results.
However as the algo minmax is called twice, the execution time is twice.
Is it possible to optimize this with one call to the minmax algo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to optimize this with single call to `minmax_element` because `minmax_element` is not the best solution for this problem.

If you insist on some STL algorithm, use `accumulate`:

```
std::accumulate(begin(contour), end(contour), Bound{}, [](Bound acc, Point p)
{
    return Bound{minpos(acc.bottomleft, p), maxpos(acc.topright, p)};
});
```

But this needs some preparations:

```
#include <numeric>

struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;

    Point(int x, int y)
        : x(x), y(y) {}
};

Point minpos(Point a, Point b)
{
    return {std::min(a.x, b.x), std::min(a.y, b.y)};
}

Point maxpos(Point a, Point b)
{
    return {std::max(a.x, b.x), std::max(a.y, b.y)};
}

struct Bound
{
    Point bottomleft;
    Point topright;

    Bound(Point bl = {640, 480}, Point tr = {0, 0})
        : bottomleft(bl), topright(tr) {}
};
```

Comparing `accumulate` approach to range for loop approach, we could consider two aspects:

1. Readability. `accumulate` approach slightly better expresses the intent of collecting a single bounding box out of several points. But it results in slightly longer code.
2. Performance. For both approaches gcc (5.3 and 6) generates almost identical code. Clang 3.8 can vectorize range for loop but can not do it for `accumulate`. Starting from C++17 we'll get parallelizm TS standardized. Parallel counterpart of `accumulate` would be `reduce` algorithm, so `accumulate/reduce` approach would allow some more flexibility.

Conclusion: both range for and `accumulate/reduce` have some (dis)advantages. But probably a completely different approach would be the best one: if `cv::Point` in OP means that you use openCV library, then the same library has [boundingRect](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gacb413ddce8e48ff3ca61ed7cf626a366) function which does exactly what you are trying to implement.

Comment: I was hopping STL algorithms would be more efficient in terms of code length.  For range is simpler. But you answered my question!
And at the end, I will use the openCV boundingRect function.

Answer (score 6):

`minmax_element` runs the comparison on `Point` objects and will return `Point` objects.

The `x` and `y` values are independent and it is likely that the `min(x)` and `min(y)` will belong to different objects.

I would use `for range` for this particular case.

```
Min = Point(640, 480) ;
Max = Point(0,0) ;
for (auto &p : contour)
{
    Min.x = std::min(p.x, Min.x)
    Min.y = std::min(p.y, Min.y)
    Max.x = std::max(p.x, Max.x)
    Max.y = std::max(p.y, Max.y)
}
```